# Android Empty Activity and Blank Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am trying to make an android project and there are many types of activities,
from there I see blank activity and empty activity.

Does anyone know the difference between the two?

Blank activity is not creating main_activity.xml but is created by empty activity.

In empty activity, I am unable to add EditText Field, Does anyone know why I am not able to add it? Error says :

```
Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

And when I open error log, there is no error

Comment: yes i am doing the same in eclipse

Comment: There are extra things that would be added to a Blank Activity, like fragment, option menu... in empty activity you need to add them yourself, if you need help with the edit text, post the code so we can help you better.

Comment: @bassel Serio but blank activity does not contain activity_main.xml why is that happeining ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check which API level you're using for rendering the view. In my case it was API 20 (for Android Wear). I changed it to API 19 and the error is gone.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my case, same to you blank activity don't generate java&layout but empty activity works well.
EditText could use with API20, API21. (BTW blank activity worked well with previous installed).

Answer (score 0):

Blank Activity: this will create a blank activity with just 1 textview.
Full Screen Activity: This is typically used by games. This activity hides the status bar and then your activity takes all screen space.
Master Detail Flow: This template creates advanced navigation, based on fragments, which will work on both tablets and phones without any change

Comment: What about the Empty activity?